# RegEx- first character should not contain special characters and subsequent characters should not contain few special characters

Tags: regex, validation

I have a specific validation scenario.

The **first character** of the string **should not contain special characters** which I can achieve using `/^[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]+$/`

But **subsequent characters should not contain specific special characters**, which are `!@$%^*+=\[\]{};:\\|<>?`

I tried that using regex `/^[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?][!@$%^*+=\[\]{};:\\|<>?]+$/` and negating the result but its not working.

I want to allow all other characters other than these special characters so I am trying to negate the result of above regex.

What I mean is, first character should accept everything except special character and subsequent chars should accept everything except specified special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.  Just missing using `^` inside a character class to negate it, and maybe `+` instead of `*` to allow an empty string.

Match start of string: `^`
Match a single character that's not one of **!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{};':"|,.<>/?**: `[^!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/\?]`
Match a string of any length that doesn't contain one of **!@$%^*+=[]{};:|<>?**: `[^!@$%^*+=\[\]{};:\\|<>\?]*`
Match end of string: `$`

Complete regex: `^[^!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/\?][^!@$%^*+=\[\]{};:\\|<>\?]*$`